How to convert image::RgbImage into rav1e::Frame
The image crate
The rav1e crate
Using the image crate between use points, I don't understand how I'm supposed to write the image data into the encoder.  I've seen the planes member of Frame which is an array of three Plane structures implying to me that the primary plane is red, secondary is green, tertiary is blue (assumption tell me if it's wrong).  Any RgbImage to be correctly formatted into a Frame, if my understanding on how rav1e works is correct will be enough to answer the question.
Also, it is worth mention, rav1e is primarily written in assembly and I can't just format the data blindly as there are architecture specific formatting applied to the data stored there.
There is no tag created for the rav1e crate.
